# Package doesn't exist

Tags: spring, maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin, sts

I'm getting an package not found error while doing maven install command.
Even I have added the dependency of my other project in it..but it still showing package not found

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.employwise</groupId>
            <artifactId>TransactionWriter</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you Updated/Refreshed the project after adding the dependency? If you are using eclipse, the option would be "Update Project"

Comment: @GauthamM I'm using sts and I have updated the project many times, but still the same error

Comment: Open the jar and check that the class is really there in the correct package. Did you compile the other project and performed an install?

Comment: @pringi other project is working fine and it is generating the jar for the project using the maven clean and maven install command. but  this project is showing an error when I run the maven install command and a jar of other projects is present in(maven dependencies folder).

Comment: It can be several things. Are you importing the correct version (0.0.1)? Is "com.employwise.TransactionWriter.Service" (package is in camel case) correct?  Is class TransactionWriterService accessible? Is dependency on your .m2 folder? Is your maven using the correct .m2 folder? Is dependency declared in the right place? Check closely each of these details and others.

Comment: @pringi correct version is used i.e 0.0.1 . yes, the package is correct and in the camel case. yes, the class is accessible. the correct .m2 folder has been used. yes, dependency is declared in the pom.xml file...still the jar is not getting created